# Updating Tags values in database (it gets duplicated)

Tags: php, mysql, tags

I have this form that send tags into my database separated with comas when i click **create** 
`POST
$query = "INSERT INTO data(tags) VALUES ('$tags')";`

and receive them when i click **edit**

```
GET
$query = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE id = $id";
$edit = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($edit)){$tags = $row['tags'];}
POST
$tags = implode(",",$_POST['tags'];
$query = "UPDATE data SET tags= '$tags' WHERE id = $id";
```

And here is the problem, When i click update button I send both previous selected tags with new selected tags and add them on the previous tags an example to understand what i typed:

- Database Tags: tag1,tag2
- Form Edit Tags: [tag1][tag2]
- Form New Tags: [tag1][tag2][tag3][tag4]
- Database Updated Tags: tag1,tag2,tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4

  `<form method="post" action="">
          <select id="tags" name="tags[]" multiple="multiple">
              <?php foreach ($tags as $tag) {echo "<option value'$tag' selected>$tag</option>";} ?>
              <option>tag1</option>
              <option>tag2</option>
              <option>tag3</option>
              <option>tag4</option>
          </select>
          <button type="submit" name="update">Submit</button>
      </form>`

Comment: `$tags = implode(",",$_POST['tags']` problem is this section, as you are using `$_POST` so it going to send what ever in `$_POST` in short your form is the problem, can you post your form code as well

Comment: @arif_suhail_123 just putted the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your data structure!

Don't store tags as a list of multiple values in a single column.  You want a table that has a single row for each item and each tag:

```
create table ItemTags (
    ItemTagId int auto_increment primary key,
    ItemId int not null,
    Tag varchar(255) not null,
    constraint fk_ItemTags_ItemId foreign key (ItemId) references Items(Item)
);
```

Then, when you want to insert a tag, just insert a tag into this table.

Why are storing multiple tags in a single column a bad idea?

- You cannot (easily) validate whether the tags are unique for a given item.
- You cannot (easily) list all tags that are being used.
- MySQL has poor string manipulation functions.
- MySQL cannot (easily) optimize queries that search for items with a single tag.

Comment: I still don't know how to make relation to database this type into my forms (two databases in single form) And i was just going to think about a way to separate each Tag and add a link into it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a function to check if Tag 1 equals the Form Tag 1. Repeat this für all tags found in the DB(foreach).
Then Update on the fly with the update function if needed.

A better aproach is to use the Array $tag, and delete all duplicates in it.

Example:

$tagArrayUni = array_unique($tag);

Comment: Can you please provide me this function? And where to put it exactly in my code?

Comment: Build it using a IF in PHP. Try to impliment it on your for each function. Another aproach is to put the tags on a Array and delete duplicates. Show the Results  thereafter. I depends on your usecase.

Comment: I'm really sorry, But i still don't understand, Can you please use my code as example?

Comment: I added a piece of code to the Answer . Hope this helps you.

Comment: Excuse me but i have a stupid question, i putted it like this
`<?php foreach ($tags as $tag) {
$tagArrayUni = array_unique($tag);
echo "<option value'$tagArrayUni ' selected>$tagArrayUni</option>";} ?>`
And here is the problem now, My selection has disappeared And when i submit a new selection the database becomes like this 
`,,,,,tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4`

Comment: Add the Array between These two:   Example:$tags = implode(",",$_POST['tags'];    $tag = array_unique($tag);
$query = "UPDATE data SET tags= '$tags' WHERE id = $id";

Comment: even with these changes is still keeping the previous tags and adds the new one that includes the previous one too.

Comment: Can you add a real example from the used tags?

Comment: > Database(Tags): TAG1,TAG2,TAG3 >>form>> EDIT*clicked* >>>> SELECT-TAGs: [TAG1][TAG2][TAG3][TAG4] >>UPDATE*clicked*>>Database>> Database(Tags): TAG1,TAG2,TAG3,TAG1,TAG2,TAG3,TAG4. They're normal Tags.

Comment: It should work. Try this: selected>$tag[1]</option>
            <option>$tag[1]</option>
            <option>$tag[2]</option>
            <option>$tag[3]</option>
            <option>$tag[4]</option>
        </select>";} ?>

Comment: Am i going to do this with every tag? i have like 100 tag, And tried it, Didn't work

Comment: Well from what i See, it should work. I do not know  your complete data structure. Or we have a misunderstanding on what you want to do.